# Is the intersection of the conjugates of a subnormal subgroup of prime power index also a subgroup of prime power index?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I was wondering if it's really the case that, if $G$ is a group with subgroups $H$ and $N$ such that $H\unlhd N\unlhd G$ such that $G/N$ and $N/H$ is a $p$-group, then the intersection of all the conjugates of $H$ in $G$ is also of $p$th power index.

This problem actually comes from a Galois Theory problem, which asks to prove that if $F\hookrightarrow K\hookrightarrow L$ are field extensions such that $K$ is Galois over $F$, and $L$ is Galois over $K$, both with $p$ groups as Galois groups, then the Galois closure of $L$ over $F$ also has a $p$ group as a Galois group.

The Galois theory solution is to note that $L$'s Galois closure is the composite field of the conjugates of $L$ in an algebraic closure of $F$, and use the fact that the degree of a composite extension divides the product of the degrees of each composite factor. But I was wondering if there were a purely group-theoretic proof of (what I think is) the corresponding statement stated in terms of the Galois groups.

Comment: What was that Galois theoretic statement again? The splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is the compositum of two cubic extensions, yet it is a sextic extension and $6\nmid 9$.

Comment: The statement is that of $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ are Galois over $K$, then $[L_1\cdots L_n:K]$ divides $[L_1:K]\cdots[L_n:K]$. This does not apply to your example since the composite factors are not Galois.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the following observation.

**Lemma.** Let $G$ be a finite group. Assume that $H_1\unlhd G$ and $H_2\unlhd G$ both have index that is a power of a prime $p$. Then $H_1\cap H_2\unlhd G$, and $[G:H_1\cap H_2]$ is also a power of $p$.

**Proof.** The normality of $H_1\cap H_2$ in $G$ is obvious. We also know that $H:=H_1H_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Because $H_1\subseteq H\subseteq G$ the index $[H:H_1]$ is a power of $p$. By one of the fundamental isomorphisms we have
$$
H/H_1\cong H_2/H_1\cap H_2.
$$
Therefore $[H_2:H_1\cap H_2]$ is a power of $p$ as well. From the formula
$$
[G:H_1\cap H_2]=[G:H_2]\cdot[H_2:H_1\cap H_2]
$$
we then infer that $[G:H_1\cap H_2]$ is a power of $p$. Q.E.D.

An induction then proves the Corollary that any finite intersection of normal subgroups of $p$-power indices also has $p$-power index. The Lemma is both the base case and the inductive step.

Turning to the claim at hand. Conjugation by an element $g\in G$ is an automorphism of $N$, so all the groups $H^g$ are normal subgroups of $N$ of a $p$-power index. Applying the Corollary to $N$ and all the conjugates $H^g$ then shows that $[N:\operatorname{core}_G(H)]$ is a power of $p$. The main claim follows from this.

---

My earlier solution (that is conceptually more complicated) striked out below. Leaving it here, because some of my algebra students lurk (or even participate!) here, and I want them to 1) know that I have blind spots, 2) develop an urge to find solutions to HW assignments that are better than what I had in mind.

---

<strike>Let $q$ be a prime, $q\neq p$. Let $Q$ be a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$. Because $[G:N]$ is a power of $p$, the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $N$ have the same size as Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$. Thus $N$ contains a conjugate of $Q$. But $N\unlhd G$, so actually $Q\le N$.</strike>

So all the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ are contained in $N$. Hence they are Sylow $q$-subgroups of $N$.

Let $H ^g$ be an arbitrary conjugate of $H$. Because conjugation by $g$ is an automorphism of $N$, we can deduce that $H^g\unlhd N$ and $[N:H^g]$ is a power of $p$. Repeating the earlier argument tells us that $H^g$ contains all the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $N$, i.e. all the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$. As this holds for all $g$ the intersection
$$
\operatorname{core}_G(H)=\bigcap_{g\in H}H^g
$$
then contains all the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$. Thus $[G:\operatorname{core}_G(H)]$ is coprime to $q$.

The argument works for all primes $q\neq p$, so we can conclude that $[G:\operatorname{core}_G(H)]$ must be a power of $p$.

Comment: Great, thanks! And of course, to finish the Galois correspondence, I'd assume that the core of $H$ is trivial, right?

Comment: @Nishant: At the very least the core is a normal subgroup of $G$. I think that suffices for the Galois theoretic argument, right?

Comment: Ah, so the core is a Galois extension of $L$ containing $F$, and this it must be the Galois closure!

Comment: Duh. I knew there had to be something simpler. Just "having a blind spot".