# Subextension of a field with Galois series of subextensions of prime degree

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $E/F$ be a field extension. Suppose $E/F$ has a finite series of subfields

$$
F = E_0 < E_1 < \cdots < E_n = E
$$

with $E_i / E_{i-1}$ Galois of degree $p$ for each $i$. In this case, call $E/F$ *special*.

**Claim: If $K$ is an intermediate field of a special extension $E/F$, then $K/F$ is also special.**

---

Things we know:

- $E/F$ has degree $p^n$ from multiplying the degrees of its subextensions, and so the degrees of $E/K$ and $K/F$ must also be $p$-powers.
- $E/F$ is separable, since each extension $E_i / E_{i-1}$ is separable and separability is transitive. Then, $E/K$ and $K/F$ are also separable since transitivity also goes in the other direction.
- If in addition $K/F$ is normal, then the claim is very simple, since $K/F$ will then be Galois, and $\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$ is then a $p$-group. We can construct a normal series of $p$-index subgroups in the Galois group, and then use the correspondence to bring them back to the desired series of fields between $F$ and $K$.
- But, $K/F$ will not be normal in general (I think). The order of its automorphism group must divide the degree of the extension, so $\mathrm{Aut}(K/F)$ must still be a $p$-group. We can still construct a normal series of $p$-index groups in the automorphism group, but I don't think then we can bring them back to fields between $F$ and $K$ (indeed, if $|\mathrm{Aut}(K/F)| \neq [K : F]$, then there will not be enough intermediate groups to bring back).

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532245/intermediate-field-extension-tower-property .

Comment: @Hermi I still don't see it (though I didn't think about this during the 6 years since this was posted). Will think more about it. I suspect that users who actually know everything about subnormal groups can answer it (or find a counterexample). If your bounty doesn't work, I will post that as a separate question and bounty it up. For now I just add a tag to attract those people :-)

Comment: The translation: Assume that $G$ is a finite group and $H\le G$ is a subnormal group of prime power index. If $M, H\le M\le G$ is any intermediate subgroup, is $M$ also subnormal?

Comment: I kept trying to search with different buzzwords. Finally I think I found [something useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/850369/11619). This is not dissimilar to the argument (+1) Lukas came up with. Too bad there aren't any good answers in the linked thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix $p$ throughout.

> **Lemma 1** Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension, where $K/k$ is any extension and let $F/k$ be any extension, then $FL/FK$ is Galois and $[FL:FK]$ divides $[L:K]$.

**Proof** $FK$ is an extension of $K$ and $FK \cdot L=FKL=FL$, so this follows from the translation theorem in Galois theory. (Theorem VI.1.12 in Lang's Algebra)

> **Lemma 2** Let $L/K$ and $E/K$ both be special, where $L$ and $E$ belong to some common field extension of $K$. Then $LE/K$ is special.

**Proof** Write $K=L_1 < L_2 <\ldots<L_n=L$ and $K=E_1 < E_2 <\ldots E_m=E$ as in the definition of being special.
Now consider $$K=L_1<\ldots < L_n=LE_1<\ldots <LE_m=LE$$

By Lemma 1, we get that $LE_{i+1}/LE_i$ is Galois for all $i$ and $[LE_{i+1}:LE_i]$ divides $[E_{i+1}:E_i]$, which has order $p$, so after eliminating trivial extensions from the tower, we win.

> **Lemma 3** Let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension. Then $L/K$ is special if and only if the Galois closure of $L/K$ is a $p$-extension. (i.e. has order $p^n$ for some $n$)

**Proof** If the Galois group $G$ of the Galois closure $E$ of $L/K$ is a $p$-group, then this follows from the well-known property of $p$-groups that for any subgroup $H < G$, we may find subgroups $H_i$ such that $H=H_1 < H_2 < \ldots < H_n=G$ such that $[H_{i+1}:H_i]=p$ for all $i$ and $H_i$ is normal in $H_{i+1}$. If we apply this to $H=\mathrm{Gal}(E/L)$, we get a tower $$H=\mathrm{Gal}(E/L)=H_1 < \ldots < H_n=G=\mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$$ Taking invariants of $E$ with respect to these subgroups implies by the Galois correspondence a tower:
$$L=E^H>E^{H_2}>\ldots>E^G=K$$
Because $[H_{i+1}:H_i]=p$ and $H_i \unlhd H_{i+1}$, we get $[E^{H_i}:E^{H_{i+1}}]=p$ and $E^{H_i}/E^{H_{i+1}}$ is Galois.

Suppose that $L/K$ is special. Let $G=\mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$, where $E$ is the Galois closure. Then for any $\sigma \in G$, we have that $\sigma(L)/K$ is special (it's just isomorphic to $L/K$). But $E$ is the compositum of all conjugates of $L$: $E=\sigma_1(L)\sigma_2(L)\cdot\ldots\cdot\sigma_n(L)$, where $\sigma_i$ runs over $G$. Thus by Lemma 2, $E/K$ is special. In particular, $E/K$ is a $p$-extension.

> **Corollary** Let $L/K$ be special, then any intermediate field $F$ of $L/K$ is also special.

**Proof** Let $E/K$ be the Galois closure of $L/K$. Then we know by Lemma 3 that $[E:K]$ is a $p$-power. The Galois closure $H$ of $F/K$ is a subextension of $E/K$, thus $[H:K]$ divides $[E:K]$ and hence $[H:K]$ is also a $p$-power. The other direction of Lemma 3 finishes the proof.