# Roots of unity and field homomorphisms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is the set of $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra homomorphisms

$$\mathbf{Q}(\mu_{\infty})\to\mathbf{C}$$
from the maximal cyclotomic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ to the complex numbers, together with its $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^{\times}$-action, the set of all primitive roots of unity in $\mathbf{C}$ with its $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^{\times}$-action?

By "the set of all primitive roots of unity in $\mathbf{C}$" we mean, calling $\nu_n$ the set of primitive $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbf{C}$, the union $\bigcup_{n\ge 3}\nu_n$. The union is disjoint by definition of primitive roots of unity, and each $\nu_n$ is acted on by $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^{\times}$ through its quotient $(\mathbf{Z}/n)^{\times}$.

Comment: @ronno I corrected the question. Thanks

Comment: One of these things is a set of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphisms. The other is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. What do you mean by "are these the same?" Are you asking if these are isomorphic $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times$-sets?

Answer (score 1):

$\widehat{\Bbb Z}^\times$ acts simply transitively on the set of $\Bbb Q$-algebra homomorphisms. This is true in greater generality: if $L/K$ is a Galois extension and $\Omega$ is any algebraically closed field containing $K$, then $K$-algebra homomorphisms $L \to \Omega$ form a simply transitive $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$-set. This implies in particular that this set is uncountable.

The set of roots of unity, on the other hand, is countable, being isomorphic to $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

But there's a relation between $\Bbb Q$-algebra homomorphism $\Bbb Q(\mu_\infty) \to \Bbb C$ and roots of unity: these homomorphisms are in bijection to automorphisms of the group of roots of unity.

Comment: Hi there. I have one unanswered question. Would you like to see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531008/subextension-of-a-field-with-galois-series-of-subextensions-of-prime-degree Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Hermi I posted a proof.