# Interpreting Galois theory: symmetry of i and -i, symmetry of $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, intuition

I usually think about Galois theory in this way (interpretation comes from my lecturer's notes from when I was at university):
Go back to the time we only had the reals. Get frustrated with there being no solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$, and consider adding a new number $i$ to remedy this. Realise that once you extend the field to include the solution $i$, you also add $-i$, another solution, and you have that $i + (-i) = 0$. There is no real difference between the two solutions, they come as a pair and add to $0$. It doesn't matter which you name $i$ and which you name $-i$ (is there even such a thing as singling one out to name it?). I have understood this to be the 2 automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}[t]/\left<t^2+1\right>$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this a consistent interpretation ? I then struggle with another example of extending $\mathbb{Q}$ to include a solution to $x^2 -2 = 0$. This time there are two automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[t]/\left<t^2-2\right>$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
When giving an isomorphism over $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Q}[t]/\left<t^2-2\right>$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $t$ may equally be mapped to either $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$.

Is the situation here analogous ? I ask because while $i$ cannot be compared to reals, only one of $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ satisfy $1<x<2$.

EDIT: By automorphism I mean a field automorphism for a field $F$. This would be a bijective map $\phi$ from $F$ to $F$ which:
_maps the additive identity (0) to the additive identity
_maps the multiplicative identity (1) to the multiplicative identity.
_preserves addition ($\phi(a + b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$)
_preserves multiplication ($\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$)

Comment: Can you write down a definition of "automorphism"?

Comment: Where does the $1<x<2$ come from? But I think the two situations are indeed analogous. Algebraically $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ enjoy the same properties. It's not until we start to worry about $<$ that there's a distinction; whereas with $\pm i$ it's when we start to worry about $\arg z$ that there's a distinction. But these are not *algebraic* properties.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger done, let me know if it is satisfactory

Comment: I agree very much with ancient mathematician. The point is in Galois Theory you're looking at $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ as a purely algebraic structure - so the only structure you know about are the field operations. It might as well be $\Bbb Q^2$ equipped with a funny multiplication. Indeed from a model theory perspective, the fact that there's an automorphism mapping $\sqrt 2\mapsto-\sqrt 2$ *proves* that the ordering $<$ on $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ can't be defined in terms of the field operations alone. (this is different to eg $\Bbb R$, where $x<y$ can be defined as $\exists t,t\ne 0\land y = x + t^2$).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. If I understand correctly I must consider $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ differently to that of $\mathbb{C}$. For example one is positive, while the other enjoys no such structure.

Comment: Yes - purely as "elements of a field extension of $\Bbb Q$", there's no way to distinguish $\sqrt 2$ and $-\sqrt 2$ in $\Bbb C$. It is certainly strange that the automorphism is discontinuous wrt the usual topology. But again, topology should have no bearing on us while we're doing algebra. It's the same as how $x \mapsto -x$ is a valid group automorphism of $\Bbb Z$ while it doesn't preserve the ordering. Another weird phenomenon is that there are three different subfields of $\Bbb C$ which are isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$, two of which are dense in $\Bbb C$..

Comment: And my pet favourite counterexample is that $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R$ are isomorphic as (additive) groups but not as topological spaces, while $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q^2$ are isomorphic as topological spaces but not as (additive) groups. It's pretty tangential but I take the moral of that to be that when you're working with bare algebraic structures you really can't reason too much about what "shape" you feel like they are.

Comment: @MrLolo The reason I asked you to do this was to point out that the definition says nothing about $<$ (ordering). Automorphisms preserve everything that can be expressed using the symbols $0,1,+,\times$. The statement $1<x<2$ cannot be expressed in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track.

But I think it's clearer to consider *embeddings* instead of automorphisms: (*)

There are two embeddings of $\mathbb{R}[t]/\langle t^2+1\rangle$ into $\mathbb{C}$: they correspond to choosing how to send the class of $t$: to $i$ or $-i$. In this sense, $\mathbb{R}[t]/\langle t^2+1\rangle$ is the *universal field* that contains $\mathbb{R}$ and a root of $t^2+1$.

In exactly the same way, there are two embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}[t]/\langle t^2-2\rangle$ into $\mathbb{C}$: they correspond to choosing how to send the class of $t$: to $\sqrt2$ or $-\sqrt2$. In this sense, $\mathbb{Q}[t]/\langle t^2-2\rangle$ is the *universal field* that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and a root of $t^2-2$.

(*) There is a school of thought that considers field extensions as embeddings. It's quiet profitable.

Comment: Thank you, this and the comments have been very helpful. Is it then fair to consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as the specific embedding of $\mathbb{Q}[t]/\left<t^2-2\right>$ into $\mathbb{C}$ where $t$ is chosen as $\sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: When you talk about embedding $\mathbb{R}[t]/\left<t^2+1\right>$ into $\mathbb{C}$ , is $i$ more specifically the element of $\mathbb{C}$ with argument $\pi/2$ ? In other words, can $\mathbb{C}$ be differentiated from the quotient field by the additional structure of a complex plane ?

Comment: To your first question: yes, it is fair to say that.

Comment: To your second question: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can certainly add extra structure to $(\Bbb C,0,1,+,\cdot)$ to allow you to distinguish $i$ from $-i$. For instance, you can distinguish them in the structure $(\Bbb C,0,1,+,\cdot,{\rm arg})$ (adding the argument function to the structure), as well as the structure $(\Bbb C,0,1,+,\cdot,{\rm Im})$ (as $i$ is the only solution to $x\cdot x+1=0$ satisfying ${\rm Im}(x)=1$). Perhaps the simplest option, though, is the structure $(\Bbb C,0,1,+,\cdot,i)$.

Comment: To explain notation: $“(\Bbb C,0,1,+,\cdot)”$ refers to the set of complex numbers where we have “access” to the constants $0$ and $1$ as well as the operations $+$ and $\cdot$. That is, it refers to the field structure of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Hi there. I have one unanswered question. Would you like to see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531008/subextension-of-a-field-with-galois-series-of-subextensions-of-prime-degree Thank you very much for your help!