# Galois cohomology of a finite cyclic group, 1st step

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $2$ whose generator is $\sigma$.
Let $M$ be $G$ module.
I want to prove Group cohomology $H^1(G,M)=Z^1(G,M)/B^1(G,M)$ is isomorphic to $ker(\sigma +1)/im(\sigma-1)$.

For the first step, I understand there is a group homomorphism from $Z^1(G,M)$ to $ker(\sigma +1)$.
The group homomorphism is $f\to f(\sigma)$ because $(1+\sigma)(f(\sigma))=f(\sigma)+\sigma f(\sigma)=f({\sigma}^2)=f(1)=0$.

But I'm stuck with proving this is bijection.

**What is the inverse map** of this map?

Thank you for youhr help.

Comment: This is not really Galois cohomology, just general group cohomology.

Comment: Your computation seems to assume that $G$ is actually or order $2$?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez. Serre's 'local fields' proves this with abstract way(not constructing concrete map), and Washington's 'Galois cohomology' omits this is bijective. I have never seen the book which proves this map is bijective.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez.  Thank you very much, I didn't know that book. What I want to do is to construct concrete map. In my question, can you describe what the inverse map is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m \in M$ be in the kernel of $\sigma + 1$.

There is a unique cocycle $\xi \in Z^1(G, M)$ with $\xi(1) = 0$ and $\xi(\sigma) = m$ (the only cocycle rule to check is $\xi(\sigma^2) = \sigma \xi(\sigma) + \xi(\sigma)$, but that simplifies to $0 = \sigma m + m$, which is true).

If we modify $m$ by an element of the form $\sigma n - n$, then $\xi$ gets modified by the function $\sigma \mapsto \sigma n - n$, which is a coboundary. So this gives the inverse map $\ker(\sigma+1)/\text{im}(\sigma - 1) \to H^1(G, M)$.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there's no reason to think about quotients. Your map is an isomorphism from $Z^1(G, M)$ to the kernel of $\sigma + 1$, and this isomorphism carries $B^1(G, M)$ to the image of $\sigma - 1$.

Comment: Hi there. I have one unanswered question. Would you like to see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531008/subextension-of-a-field-with-galois-series-of-subextensions-of-prime-degree Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @hunter Could you tell me why there is a unique cocycle $ξ$ with $$ξ(1)=0$,$ξ(\sigma)=m$ ?

Comment: @Pont for uniqueness: a cocycle is a particular type of function, $G$ has two elements, and I told you what $\xi$ did to both of them. For existence: you just have to check that $\xi(1 \cdot \sigma)$, $\xi(1 \cdot 1)$, and $\xi(\sigma \cdot \sigma)$ expand correctly according to the cocycle formula, and the ones involving $1$ reduce to $0=0$. The other computation is shown in the answer.